# Lua 5.3 variable argument function in metatable

Tags: lua

I have a function as follows:

```
local function mytest(...)
    local args={...}
    if(#args==1 and type(args[1])=="table") then
        local x, mean=nil, nil
        for k,v in pairs(args[1]) do 
            k=string.lower(k)
            if(k=="x") then x=v
            elseif(k=="mean") mean=v

           --the rest is omitted for brevity
end
```

Then right after the function (in the same script file), I have the following lines:

```
mytable.test={}
mytable.test.mt={}
mytable.test.mt.__call=mytest

setmetatable(mytable.test, mytable.test.mt)
```

where `mytable` is some table in the global space.

When I call the function as follows:

```
mytable.test{x=Vec, mean=3}
```

where `Vec` is of type userdata, it seems that the type of `Vec` and type of `mean` are not correctly passed to the local function. As a matter of fact, both seems to be passed as table. However, if I introduce in the following way:

```
mytable.test=mytest
```

then everything works as expected. Not sure what point I am missing.

Comment: `if(k=="x") then x=v`  Is `x` global variable?  Hasn't it been occasionally overwritten by something else?

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a runnable version of the code that includes `print` statements along with what output you expect and what output you get. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated the question. Both `x` and `mean` are local variables.

Comment: Possibly, the issue is that the first argument passed to `__call` is the table being called. So `mytable.test{x=Vec, mean=3}` actually passes 2 arguments.

Comment: @luther: You might be right. How can I correctly pass it.

Comment: Maybe add a `self` parameter to `mytest` before the `...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from Luther, the following change solves the problem:

```
mytable.test={}
mytable.test.mt={}
setmetatable(mytable.test, mytable.test.mt)

function mytable.test.mt:__call(...)
    return mytest(...)
end
```